# Unhandled Exception during Handshake in BitTorrent protocol implementation

Tags: python, protocols, bittorrent, peer

I'm working on a BitTorrent client, more specifically, on the BitTorrent protocol implementation, and I've encountered a bug that results in an unhandled exception during the handshake process. This behavior is consistent and occurs whenever I try to establish a connection with a peer.

When attempting to open a connection and perform the BitTorrent handshake using the provided `protocol.py`, the following exception is raised:

> ProtocolError: Unable to receive and parse a handshake

This issue is preventing the successful initiation of a handshake, leading to unsuccessful connections with peers.

Relevant part of code:

```
response = Handshake.decode(buf[:Handshake.length])
if not response:
    raise ProtocolError('Unable to receive and parse a handshake')
```

I expect the BitTorrent client to establish a successful connection with peers and complete the handshake process without raising any exceptions. But, it's not happening.

I've tried to troubleshoot it on my own by checking my network configuration, and other related parts of my code, but I've been unable to identify the cause of the error.

What could be causing the unhandled exception during the handshake process in the provided code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing what state the program is in and what data you have received.

I'd use

- a debugger tostep through the code and see what happens. Or do poor man's debugging and add print statements.
- wireshark to see what goes over the network
- `strace` to see which system calls (primarily network IO) the program is making prior to the error